# Bound integral equation derivation for smooth boundary.

Tags: integration, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, greens-theorem

My task is to derive  $\frac{1}{2} T(p)= \int_{\infty} [G(p,p')\frac{\partial T(p')}{\partial n} - T(p')\frac{\partial G(p,p')}{\partial n}] dS , p \in \partial \Omega$(smooth)

from

$T(p)= \int_{\partial\Omega} [G(p,p')\frac{\partial T(p')}{\partial n} - T(p')\frac{\partial G(p,p')}{\partial n}] dS , p \in \Omega $

Note p is the vector (x,y) in two dimensions.

I am struggling to understand the concepts behind this therefore do not have a starting point for this problem. I have undertaken some research online but can not find anything to help me derive this equation.

Comment: What's $T$ and $G$? I'm guessing $T$ is arbitrary and $G$ is the Green's function of some problem.

Comment: Working from the fact T is a function such that $\nabla ^2 T(p)=0 $ (Laplace ) and G is from the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is called Green's third identity, and it comes about by integrating the relation $G(p,p') \nabla^2 T(p')=0$ with respect to $p'$, over $\Omega$ with a disk centered at $p$ removed. You integrate by parts twice and then contract the disk to a point, and the separate $T(p)$ term comes from the integral over the tiny circle, which does not go to zero even as the disk is contracted.

You can imitate this derivation with a point located on the boundary, where you exclude a disk centered at the point on the boundary. But now the disk isn't really a disk, it is the intersection of the disk with the domain, which is always a proper subset of the disk no matter how small the disk is.

In general this intersection is some funny shape, but for small radius and smooth boundary, the intersection is approximately a half-disk, essentially because a small enough piece of a smooth boundary is approximately straight. (You can visualize a piece of the boundary playing the role of the diameter of the half-disk.)

Now the $1/2 T(p)$ comes about from the integral over the tiny semicircle, with the 1/2 appearing because this semicircle is half as long as the circle was in the off-boundary case.

Note that there are some subtleties going on here: for example the value of $T(p)$ that is really appearing on the right hand side is the limit of $T(p')$ as $p'$ approaches $p$ from inside the domain.

Comment: So even though my p'=(x',y') ie G(p,p')=(x,y,x', y'). I take the limit as p' $\to$ p.

Comment: @math2020 Yes; I'm not sure what alternative you would have in mind (maybe going along axes or something).

Comment: Sorry, just trying to get my head around it. So do I approach this as having a small radius  $\varepsilon$ , then  $\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\partial \Omega _\varepsilon } G(p,p')\frac{\partial T(p')}{\partial n} - T(p')\frac{\partial G(p,p')}{\partial n}] dS_\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2} T(p') $ then we claim $\lim_{p' \to p} T(p') = T(p).$

Comment: @math2020 That's not exactly what I meant. The point is that in the limit, $1/2 T(p)$ is appearing from the integral on the semicircle, where by virtue of continuity of $T$ you expect that it doesn't change appreciably. But the semicircle is inside the domain. So really the value that is being approached by $T$ on these tiny semicircles is $\lim_{p' \to p} T(p')$, not necessarily $T(p)$. $T(p)$ itself is not necessarily even well-defined in physical problems, for example when the boundary separates two domains from each other you will often have two different limiting values from each side.

Comment: @math2020 The same thing is true in the other integrals where you aren't worrying about the singularity: what we call $T$ on the boundary is $\lim_{p' \to p} T(p')$ taken from inside the domain, which is "what the PDE sees $T(p)$ being".